# What is a good database of galaxy luminosities?

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, astronomy, galaxies, data

I need to do some mass/luminosity relationship calculations.  Where can I find good, referenceable absolute luminosity data?

Comment: Have you tried https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/?

Comment: That's just what I was looking for.  Is it safe to use the Visible wavelength for the M/L ratio?

Comment: It likely depends on the application, and the subset of galaxies you're comparing. Remember that galaxies with different stellar populations (e.g. elliptical vs. irregular) have different fractions of their luminosity in different bands.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question.  I've seen M/L ratios referenced in several articles.  Sometimes the band is included (e.g. $M/L_v$), but often it isn't.  When I see someone quote an M/L ratio without qualification, is there an assumed band?

Comment: That's different enough that it probably deserves to be a separate question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NASA/IPAC Extragalactic Database (NED) aggregates most of the relevant data for most of the galaxies that have ever been observed, including luminosities: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/.